# Daily reports by C#.NET console application

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have a task which is to create a C# console application which should generate daily reports in Excel format. The reports should be generated daily except Sunday.

My question is How to  genereate daily tasks(scheduled tasks) using task scheduler in C# console application?

Any help or tutorials is appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the reports built in SSRS? Knowing that the report data is in SQL Server doesn't really help define how the reports are defined.

Comment: You ask way to many things in one question. How to query an SQL database, how to generate Excel reports and how to schedule a command line application. Please create separate questions for each part and try to elaborate a little bit on what you have tried.

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo - That's funny I didn't see a single question in there anywhere.

Comment: I don't need about Exporting excel and about Sqlserver. I just needed the information about how to genereate  daily tasks..

Comment: @M.S.Nayak - Where in what you said does it say that?

Comment: @M.Babcock I will edit my question that way of asking is confusing What i required is exact Uwe Keim's post bellow.

Comment: @M.S.Nayak - Feel free to straighten out your question, but based on where it is now you may be better off closing it and starting over again because the 'question' you've asked above is nowhere near a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably your question is much to broad.

To still give you an idea on how to start, here are some hints:

- Write a .NET console application.
- Use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to periodically run the application.
- Use [Aspose.Cells](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial) to generate your Excel documents.
- Use the [`MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx) and `SmtpClient` class to send the Excel documents by email.

I did similar working applications in the past with the above components.

Comment: Ya I required Exactly same.. :) much concentrated on  Windows Task Scheduler and  MailMessage.

Comment: Can you give me examples how i can use Windows Task Scheduler in C# console application Please I googled but could not get better examples. please

Comment: From my understanding you do _not_ program the Task Scheduler but instead XCOPY your console application (the EXE file + all DLLs) to your server and then use the admin GUI to schedule your application.

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL Server, you also have [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx)!

Reporting Services allows you to:

- define a report with a visual designer
- fetch data from SQL Server
- arrange it, aggregate it
- export the result to any number of formats - Excel, Word, PDF, HTML - you name it
- **schedule reports** to be run at specific times (e.g. every night except Sunday, at 3am)
- **e-mail report output** to a given list of users

Comment: +1 though I'm still uncertain what they are asking. The title has reports in it and its tagged with C# so I assume SSRS fits in somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for Information.in my case But  reports are not SSRS .

Answer (score 0):

Use a library like [ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/) to generate the excel file using data that you can simply load by ADO.NET or Entity Framework.